# SELECT difference in record count between 28 days

Tags: oracle

I have a table which logs record counts of all tables in a schema every 28 days. The table has the following columns:
    "TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "RECORD_COUNT" NUMBER, 
    "CREATED" DATE

I would like to spool out a log file which has the following data:

1. Table Name
2. Current Record Count
3. Record Count 28days ago
4. Difference between2 and 3

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it

```
SELECT table_name,
       record_count,
       prior_record_count,
       record_count - prior_record_count diff
  FROM (SELECT table_name,
               record_count,
               lag(record_count) 
                  over (partition by table_name
                            order by created) prior_record_count,
               rank() 
                 over (partition by table_name
                           order by created) rnk
           FROM <<name of table>>)
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to partition by table name.  Good answer.

Comment: Justin I get an error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 28 Column: 1

Comment: I made some minor edits and its working now. SELECT table_name,
       record_count,
       prior_record_count,
       record_count - prior_record_count diff
  FROM (SELECT table_name,
               record_count,
               lag(record_count) over (partition by table_name order by created) prior_record_count,
               rank() over (partition by table_name order by created) rnk
           FROM  TABLE1)
 WHERE rnk = 2

Comment: @Ram - Sorry about that, I missed a comma in the subquery.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's LAG function should give you what you need.  It's an analytical function that returns data from the previous row.  The following should work:

```
select
    table_name,
    record_count,
    prev_record_count,
    record_count - nvl(previous_record_count, 0) as difference
from (
    select
       table_name,
        record_count,
        lag(record_count) over (order by created) as prev_record_count
    from
        log_table
);
```

Comment: Danimal, There is also a null record showing up in the result. My table has: Record1-Table1,580,23-JAN-12,Record2-Table1,580,20-FEB-12. Your query returns: Record1-Table1,580,(null),(null)  
Record2-Table1,580,580,0